# How to install Redis Slave on App Engine Flex

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

I have deployed a .Net core app on App Engine Flex. My App Engine Flex is configured as Auto Scaling. My app is using Memorystore Redis. I want each instance to have their own Redis Slave (Memorystore Redis will be master) so that each instance can read from their local Redis instance which will improve the performance of the app. I am using the reference from https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/ede954da6de61f1d6a8572db4cd7bdf1278a2815/4.0/Dockerfile

How can I install and run Redis Slave on an App Engine Flex?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Google offers some tutorials that could help you accomplish what you want. The following  might provide you with the information you need:

1. [Connecting to a Redis instance from an App Engine Flexible Environment application](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-flex)
2. [Connect to Redis from Node.js on App Engine flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-redis-on-appengine)

I also recommend checking the [High availability documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/high-availability) and the [Overview of Cloud Memorystore for Redis documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/redis-overview) for more information about the proper Redis configuration for high availability with Memorystore.

---